# Double tap to Zoom with UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, zooming, uigesturerecognizer

I am using Apple's source code.  I am sure there is just a snippet that I have messed up. I have a form that I have made programmatically.  When I double tap the recognizer fires and goes through the motions but I it won't actually zoom.  Any suggestions? Thanks for the help

```
imageScrollView.delegate=self;

CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
imageScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
imageScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(750,1250);
imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale=5.0;
[imageScrollView setZoomScale:imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale];
self.view=imageScrollView;
[imageScrollView release];
```

Added a bunch of UItextfields/labels to the scrollview.
    aircraftType = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 32, 150, 15)];
    aircraftType.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    aircraftType.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    aircraftType.placeholder = @"Aicraft Type";
    aircraftType.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:aircraftType];

```
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in

    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];

}


#pragma mark Utility methods
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates.
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);



    return zoomRect;
}
```